# setOnItemSelectedListener() not called after asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, onclicklistener, android-spinner

I've a problem with a custom spinner. Pratically, I'm loading a spinner by query and I'm using a specific Asynctask.
After the asynctask I should call the method setOnItemSelectedListener() but doesn't work: when I launch the app, the method wasn't invoked.
I don't understand where I wrong...can you help me?

This is my code:

```
//other code

                if (firstpopulate)
                {
                    new LoadSpinnerJobs().execute();
                    firstpopulate = false;
                }


                drawerHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
                    {
                        // do work
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    }
                });

//other code

        public class LoadSpinnerJobs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<SpinnerItem>>
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                super.onPreExecute();
                userList = new ArrayList<SpinnerItem>();
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected List<SpinnerItem> doInBackground(Void... voids)
            {
                DbHelperJob findjob = new DbHelperJob(context);

                try
                {
                    QueryBuilder<Job, String> queryBuilder = findjob.getJobDao().queryBuilder();
                    List<Job> results = queryBuilder.selectColumns("ID_JOB", "NAME_JOB", "TASK_JOB").orderBy("DEFAULT_JOB", false).query();

                    for (Job a : results)
                    {
                        Log.v("result: ", "aggiungo job");
                        userList.add(new SpinnerItem(String.valueOf(a.getId()), a.getName_job(),a.getName_task()));
                    }
                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    Log.v("exc: ", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return userList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<SpinnerItem> result)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.v("post: ", "setto spinner");
                CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(context,R.layout.custom_spinner_item, userList);
                drawerHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it. What exactly goes wrong? Is there an exception or does the listener just not fire?

Comment: Nothing exception. :(
I've tried to debug it. There aren't problems. Simply, the setOnItemSelectedListener() was skipped...

Comment: Yes, I think that the listener just not fire...

Comment: What do you mean with skipped? The line `drawerHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(...` was skipped? Cannot happen according to your code. However I don't think your problem has anything to do with the AsyncTask. How about posting some more of your "other code" instead?

Comment: yes, the entire "drawerHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(..." was skipped. Anyway, if I remove the asynctask and execute the query without asynctask, it works perfectly.

Comment: Found your problem -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your 'drawerHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);' in the `onPostExecute()` method.
As AsyncTask is executed in parallel to the main thread, the sequence of executed code is like this:

1. execute AsyncTask
2. set Listener
3. set Adapter

Setting the adapter after setting the listener, removes the listener again.
So you have to set the listener within `onPostExecute()` after you set the adapter.